# java ADF - Add pop up to confirm when leaving a page

Tags: java, richfaces, oracle-adf

They are developing a web-application at my company using java ADF richfaces, to make it simple lets say we have two pages, a login page then the home page.

After logging in, i start to work normally and then by mistake i click on "close tab" in my browser, here i would loose all my work if not saved and i thought about a simple feature to ask developers to implement;

Add a pop-up window to confirm to user if he really wants to leave the page, but the java developers said such feature is impossible to implement.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your developers don't know about [onUnload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) and [onBeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) javascript event. It is supported by all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

ADF uses the uncommitted data warning http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.de/2010/02/adf-faces-rc-afdocument.html